# Reset class member

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, stdmap

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void SetData(std::string key, int value) 
    { 
        if(m_data.find(key) != m_data.end()) m_data.at(key) = value;
        else m_data.insert(std::make_pair(key,value));
    }
    int GetData(std::string key)
    {
        if(m_data.find(key) != m_data.end()) return m_data.at(key);
        return 0;
    }
    void ResetData()
    {
        for(auto item : m_data)
            item.second = 0;
    }
    void ResetData2()
    {
        for(auto it=m_data.begin(); it!=m_data.end(); it++)
            (*it).second = 0;
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, int> m_data;
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
    a.SetData("KEY1", 10);
    std::cout << "Key1: " << a.GetData("KEY1") << std::endl;
    a.ResetData();
    std::cout << "Key1: " << a.GetData("KEY1") << std::endl;
    a.ResetData2();
    std::cout << "Key1: " << a.GetData("KEY1") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Key1: 10
Key1: 10
Key1: 0
```

Live demo: https://ideone.com/GH3Ft8

What's the difference between the two reset methods here?
Resetting the class member `std::map<std::string, int> m_data` with iterator approach (`ResetData2()`) works like expected but not range based loop (`ResetData()`)!

Comment: `auto item` this makes a copy of each element in the map, you want `auto& item`

Comment: reference and value auto& on first reset solves it.

Comment: Interesting belt-and-suspenders code: search for a key in the container, and if it's found, do a (redundant) bounds-checked access to update its associated value. Once you've done the search, use `m_data[key]` rather than `m_data.at(key)`. And even better, note that `find` returns an iterator that points at the matching element; you can use that iterator to assign a new value, without repeating the search.

Comment: Short version of SetData: `m_data[key] = value;`

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you for the improvement ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method should modify a *reference* to each item

```
void ResetData()
{
    for(auto& item : m_data)
        item.second = 0;
}
```

Otherwise you are setting the value to zero for a *copy* of each item in your map.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
for(auto item : m_data)
```

It creates a copy of your key-value For what you want, use:

```
for(auto &item: m_data)
```